# Touchpad feedback in linux?

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad

How to execute a command on every touchpad tap? I am constantly losing clicks (taps) on my touchpad, and situation doesn't seem to improve with new updates. I want to add a click sound for each successfull tap, so I don't have to wait for the clicks that did not happen. Also I would like to distinguish left/right and middle tap types (do different actions for each).

The solution must have acceptably low latency and not to be bound to a specific touchpad model. Also programatic solutions are welcome too (e.g. u can use library XYZ to implement this yourself).

I asked for a custom command, because in future I want to put a vibromotor under the touchpad (from a phone) for feedback.

Please, refrain from suggestions to fix the touchpad driver, because I would like this feature even on a perfectly working touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are asking for is impossible, and you ?arbitrarily? limit the solution space in a way that aggravates this.  "Tap" events generally get processed to become button clicks, and applications don't (can't) know the difference.

Note that it is up to the touchpad implementation to decide what IS and what IS NOT a tap (if the touch is too long, you just cursor).

Any possible solution is going to include getting information from the touchpad device or driver, prior to the point where the events become buttons--unless you are willing to have the same behavior on mechanical clicks, in which case, just get the reports and...enjoy.